Copyright free species image database
I assume that there are several websites with licence-free photographs of animals, plants, fungi, etc. (properly identified at species level, of course), but I have not been able to find them. Can you tell me which sites you know of?
Thanks in advance!

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about biology, but a general question about resources showing no evidence of any attempt of the poster to find the information for himself.

It depends in part by what you mean by "licence-free photographs".  Many photos are available which are free to use if one credits the author and/or references the license terms.  If you mean free to use in any way without restriction, that is (in the U.S. at least) ones in the "public domain",   I'm not aware of sites that have only public domain photos and identify by species.
However there are sites where one can find such photos (at times).  Specifically, one is "commons.wikimedia.org".  To search for such photos there, one has to do a qualified search.  One way is to go to the search page, select "Search in: File" from the list of "namespaces", and search for the species name along with the quoted string "work is in the public domain". You'll then have to check the "File:" page of one you might want to use to assure it's in the public domain for the country you want to publish it in.
